# Not receiving all data with async socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous

So, I have an async socket setup but when I read the data not all of is received. Sometimes most data will be received, then other times it won't. Then it hangs on a part of my program because it didn't receive the data to parse/handle.

Code:

```
public static void OnArrival(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    connection = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    string data;
    try
    {
        int bytesRead = connection.EndReceive(ar);
        if (Sock.IsConnected(connection))
        {
            connection.BeginReceive(BufferData, 0, BufferData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnArrival), connection);
        }
        else
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BufferData, 0, bytesRead);
            HandleData.ProcessData(connection, data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteError(ex.ToString());
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

When HandleData.ProcessData is called, not all of the data is received.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `BufferData` before `BeginReceive` has completed. Either switch to sync IO or implement async IO properly (with callbacks or tasks).